# List of Complete Xcode Version & Device Name/OS for Travis CI?

Tags: ios, xcode, yaml, travis-ci

I am updating a repo of mine ([STAControls](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls)) to have up-to-date continuous integration test via TravisCI. The problem I am encountering is I will get errors like so:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:9.1, name:iPad Pro }
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
```

Which can be [viewed here](https://travis-ci.org/Stunner/STAControls/jobs/334979071).

Now obviously, the issue in this example is that there was no iPad Pro that launched on iOS 9 (iOS 10 was the OS it launched on IIRC) but I am getting [several other errors like this](https://travis-ci.org/Stunner/STAControls/builds/334979057) for the rest of the build for less obvious reasons.

***So here is my question:*** Is there any place where I can get a comprehensive list of **Xcode versions**, **devices**, and **OS**es that work for TravisCI? (A [travis.yml config similar to the one in my project](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/.travis.yml) would be ideal.) It would really save me from pushing up a crapload of commits due to trial & error. Thanks.

Before you point me to their docs, I have already seen [this page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx) which contains a lot of the information I need, but omits device names, and upon further inspection of the error, it turns out their documentation isn't quite precise as iOS 10.3 isn't available on Xcode 9.2, 10.3.1 is.

Comment: there is `Available destinations for the "STAControlsTests" scheme:` in the log where it lists all the devices with iOS version.

Comment: Yep you are right. Can't believe I missed that! If you make your comment into an answer (with some elaboration) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get available XCode Version and available iOS versions for them here [Xcode version](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx#Xcode-version).

And, If you see the logs in build you can see just below the error `Available destinations for the "STAControlsTests" scheme:` It lists all the available devices with their details:

```
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D56CF125-0398-405C-BCAD-7CD5C8DE9C81, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D8A65111-E485-4F8C-A037-09F81F14618F, OS:8.1, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D2EA2E24-A1CF-460A-9390-0E28870FC28A, OS:8.2, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8F1F79AE-0086-419A-91D4-B5D3AED3D0A5, OS:8.3, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:15F8B4D6-FADF-4DCD-BF06-66B232D8F334, OS:8.4, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9B792A1C-B89B-43EA-8D3F-BC215DF59D19, OS:9.0, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2FE15DA4-5EC7-49A5-B78D-F429AB6AB7F9, OS:9.1, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:382B796A-5862-4822-967C-63D92A972A84, OS:9.2, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6A0D249C-296B-4C4F-B650-70DB3BBCD337, OS:9.3, name:iPad 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F8F3C85E-496E-471F-8435-193A3842ACD3, OS:8.1, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CA27D11D-AC02-4380-AEBA-EB4C28C38A64, OS:8.2, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FE5B62B5-DAAA-4798-8197-B7C2E32F8B61, OS:8.3, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:02611222-B414-423B-8B8A-FD65E57A2826, OS:8.4, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:23654F4B-2EEB-4B94-8AFA-E0C38FA043DC, OS:9.0, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CA9E3B4B-31F3-42C6-9B81-0AFD03C14E69, OS:9.1, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A2CD03C7-05DC-407A-A117-00DDC71A8F7A, OS:9.2, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DF9AD210-D565-4FF7-8C30-8117CC1A8ABA, OS:9.3, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FFDCEC43-BE2D-46EA-98AA-5643F6882D39, OS:10.0, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7D24634B-067E-488D-A025-0F45B7467F73, OS:10.1, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5DEF0377-1447-4D52-B267-8BEDC0D1078A, OS:10.2, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1927ED75-E56F-48F5-BE19-ECDD09BFDDC9, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Air }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:75CEA576-8113-46FC-9723-E89A2D65FD38, OS:8.1, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7B3B5E2A-5071-4472-BA40-DFE991BCFA0F, OS:8.2, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8808ED62-F13B-422D-8C0C-565319421049, OS:8.3, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E6F5F8EC-BD06-4887-AD55-A1802830FF39, OS:8.4, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:36EDE922-FE12-412F-B558-E2E0F0CA3DE9, OS:9.0, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BE431EDF-3763-431D-B9B6-5F27E9C9B434, OS:9.1, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:721B5B33-6CB6-4256-9690-A9474C066EF4, OS:9.2, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D83D9FC9-4AFB-41AC-A04B-755635DABF7D, OS:9.3, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C1D9D0E2-BADE-48B8-8F38-398AEE1BE434, OS:10.0, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A3BF55FB-82C5-4F3D-B3E8-B1A4A4AB2490, OS:10.1, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC36DD93-1472-47DA-A4D3-302F2006B3E0, OS:10.2, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F00561A4-57DE-4146-B45C-A116D4F4FF92, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Air 2 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:831AB357-8223-490A-B6AA-CCF1377C063B, OS:10.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:139166B7-67C4-4C7B-9EAE-8CCD9E5E7AE0, OS:10.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5D06A5D6-7BEC-4EA1-8DD0-31B28B5F1354, OS:10.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:59DB07B1-DAD3-4BF2-8FCE-DCD219454151, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3B4D63B0-1BFB-4921-B288-B213267B206B, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6B9FA8D3-569E-42F3-83E5-D80EC064B81C, OS:9.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:070DF22F-7F69-4EAA-896E-2E84DAE10B2F, OS:9.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:02A8F368-DAF1-4473-AE19-AB2B6F8ABF13, OS:9.3, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AE225816-423F-4755-B1A3-944D0B77081B, OS:10.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B43EE7DB-32F3-4A14-9633-4CA9C3C054EB, OS:10.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:562297E5-5A28-4498-A22E-3B3B6F33E21B, OS:10.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:504A99DA-1807-4319-8B67-6DCE38E0EC9A, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:31661071-4A00-4068-9BCF-2B1109B66347, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6C414B17-8F7E-4B7A-84CF-5C486C9252AF, OS:8.1, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:547FDA94-BC57-4E28-911F-CBE83883220B, OS:8.2, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:083294ED-5204-4716-B125-5BBA64E699DE, OS:8.3, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7106EA7A-20EA-4DCF-ACC5-24EF605D6C2F, OS:8.4, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A0FD7022-B1C6-4F48-B81F-EC8BB41E3669, OS:9.0, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FC3B9221-1A5E-442C-9D96-015C90752034, OS:9.1, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E012273-3F93-446E-8E77-0460470032E4, OS:9.2, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:16886F87-54C0-4396-BDFD-20017FA3BD58, OS:9.3, name:iPad Retina }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DCAF3602-A974-48F4-B6B6-8247F7BE4290, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DCDC5358-FFBF-4989-8092-7F65ED8F02AF, OS:8.2, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2725F258-12B4-4EC0-BF92-2F6972815E5B, OS:8.3, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:781CBE8C-F7A2-4F43-B860-D5FE770AB9CC, OS:8.4, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:95CABF9C-189B-4EC0-AC51-2BE373A29E95, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F34DC048-527F-4281-858D-E2E3DC5D32DA, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:75838F3E-BE3C-43E0-BC20-E725CC43435D, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:984A1890-994E-4381-ABDC-7A302426E9AF, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 4s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C6895639-ADC2-4EF8-8BE1-3235EC600C6F, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3519E18E-DEFE-465F-9716-9CE03EEDCFDB, OS:8.2, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D8101339-3F2D-4784-AE7F-0C0C38717431, OS:8.3, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2FDCE5B5-CE70-4DC9-AD28-342517146F0D, OS:8.4, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5910ACF-1062-48D0-8928-78018B223295, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:51682944-F136-411D-B67B-18AF8E1E2B13, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5A8FD652-C843-43BF-AC77-EA15B4A916D7, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D5BD44C1-F03E-439D-BB6C-E805A7FCA27B, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3AA26DE0-C2F0-4CAF-936D-09F1ECCF9BDA, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F5558AB4-0D25-451A-98E6-80A5661E3615, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DEF54A5A-0DB7-4752-B2B5-836A924C1960, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2523EF7F-852D-4268-A9A3-C55A4428EAE0, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 5 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A910963-385E-4A7C-810E-BCFF684B5564, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:47B1A2B3-6190-4915-9406-6B71257262C8, OS:8.2, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DDDC024F-D1B1-4DD4-BED0-3DDF2780232D, OS:8.3, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8588DD30-E67A-4B43-BEBC-8CCAC82F8338, OS:8.4, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B6DE063E-0F3E-43F5-8020-0BEBF00D6E4A, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:14434056-BA7C-42DF-9683-6BB25D6001AB, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B5D50293-B1BA-420A-B7BA-316BAEE71461, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EB62DE7F-9FD2-4C76-BF28-E31659A93174, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:109C3283-E302-42ED-BCF4-7B46B05AD70C, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7254AB8A-B3F9-4213-81D0-5F6D102639F2, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7622058D-CCEF-41D9-B698-FB6ACE4AD737, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9C7E2899-7A4D-4277-9DBE-9E873EAFFFA5, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 5s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:80BE80F4-C243-43F0-BD95-5CB085DAD04F, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A14A9B20-991D-4837-BADE-A98DB2D7FB61, OS:8.2, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:03CE767F-846C-484D-9891-30E38ABD5143, OS:8.3, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:407BD90E-2507-4133-A823-8E0407EE8D69, OS:8.4, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2BD86C3D-EFC9-4770-82B7-C5E03444AE16, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:309333F7-3DAE-403C-A688-865986C623B4, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D07AD1E1-0CC7-4472-BD6A-2932A3A74634, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:03760B35-0E00-4F7C-87BF-7C4F59EF7248, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8BCFD96E-24E3-44B4-AE9F-F87F0D669A3F, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:57843F60-3483-4859-94F5-5510A5974107, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:58E11FF8-014D-4141-A8AE-EFCE6EBBCFE0, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0EB7E0E4-915F-497E-9D1C-934A10FA82E3, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 6 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:25920468-1144-4E9B-AC25-41C79D2DC107, OS:8.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:25E030F7-A8FC-47D6-90CF-F49FF4D98622, OS:8.2, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AEB1A3D5-1B9C-4BF6-BDC9-1514DC283402, OS:8.3, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0EA8243F-B321-48CE-8AD1-AFBDBCF24260, OS:8.4, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9AB3D590-C748-4E17-8E35-67B298E973F7, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A999A1E3-742E-4C02-937B-569C6FEF9B93, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E0697259-F09E-4630-B389-46FFEFB722AB, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1627EF4F-03B1-4635-9270-FC3E7FE5A13A, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B9814467-D104-489A-BB92-93927D044C73, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FCEE34EB-BAE7-4FB5-BD10-E2B08A42B5F2, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4CE9FA46-5B35-4FE8-A4BD-994E4540DC37, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EEE357DD-82EF-43B5-AABC-27E3B59DB403, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:70D9F230-1F07-4C14-9ED2-FE03D88FEAC4, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CE78B177-986F-44E9-86FA-634545685321, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC8E5E63-85C7-49CD-A967-4CE2F08F00D3, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8BB869B7-8203-4B31-99C9-CC276640EC3D, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9B32ADCD-2A13-4569-81A1-0279124E5831, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:55B3CE57-115D-48A2-B11C-5A2A6377F302, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:02F238E7-3BBF-4E54-8D8B-334EBDA944A4, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AB104968-7058-4AE2-A95D-DBB77634C642, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 6s }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9D345279-B4F5-42A1-8202-95444A73E610, OS:9.0, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2F456EE1-0567-438C-A5F2-57A8D1230CE6, OS:9.1, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:68B1E269-3412-42E3-9BEE-341D4C641DD7, OS:9.2, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:43CD88FF-F754-4EA7-BB04-D879504B943B, OS:9.3, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:89EB216A-C657-49A0-92B6-9A6D182C5F79, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DD32C29E-E93B-44BC-8BD4-00F55143D3DB, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3D764D40-5488-4063-9152-5A4A8EAD2CB8, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:482F5B24-39BD-44E0-A525-8AA39234DA28, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:15E2107D-EAD2-4E1F-8BC3-59E58E750FB1, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 7 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:060AAE67-12D1-4C9B-AD75-71A217E26F0E, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 7 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:52EB9086-AE12-46E3-AADF-EB4B2B729E23, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 7 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:ABBD7191-486B-462F-80B4-AE08C5820DA1, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1E45DDFB-C595-4087-9EF0-4864772061B7, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:55235379-EF25-4E79-BD2C-2E3A03853BFB, OS:10.1, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EEFF1355-EE6A-4E73-A6D6-42F337C1B113, OS:10.2, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F60B87EC-8969-41A7-90ED-D0826ECC32DB, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BDB7716F-DB5B-453C-BFB8-1D8B1497A931, OS:9.3, name:iPhone SE }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:ACC06281-1A0A-4A1C-848F-9F4FAA04D3CB, OS:10.0, name:iPhone SE }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:843EE95D-FF6C-483B-B6C4-50D1FC049887, OS:10.1, name:iPhone SE }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:040F19EB-FEC0-4357-B72F-3BD6A85DEF0E, OS:10.2, name:iPhone SE }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:85AF1F51-F2EB-4A4D-930B-0E5761511A45, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone SE }
```